# How to add custom middleware to express-openapi-validator using Swagger 3

Tags: node.js, swagger-3.0, express-openapi-validator

I've got a Node app using express-openapi-validator that takes a an api spec file (which is a .yml file), with request and response validation. The express-openapi-validator package routes the request to a handler file (defined in the spec). This is what one of the handlers might look like:

```
function getUsers(req, res) {
  const { 'x-user-id': userId } = req.headers
  res.status(200).json(`Your userId is ${userId}`)
}
```

I've got an API key feature, where users can get a new API key, and the other endpoints that need the caller to have the API key in the request headers to validate the request.

I know it should be possible to use middleware to validate the request, but I can't figure out how to use custom middleware with the express-openapi-validator package on select endpoints.

For eg:

GET /apikey = does not require api key
GET /resource = requires api key

How do I configure this?

Here's what the openapi validator code in my app.js looks like:

```
new OpenApiValidator({
  apiSpec,
  validateResponses: true,
  operationHandlers: path.join(__dirname, './handlers'),
})
  .install(app)
  .then(() => {
    app.use((err, _, res) => {
      res.status(err.status || 500).json({
        message: err.message,
        errors: err.errors,
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: You could use this package to add the middlewares [swagger-routes-express](https://github.com/davesag/swagger-routes-express#readme)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually ended up finding a solution for this myself.

First of all, I'm using version `4.10.5` of `express-openapi-validator`, so the code above is slightly different.

Here's what it looks like now:

```js
// index.js
app.use(
    OpenApiValidator.middleware({
      apiSpec,
      validateResponses: true,
      operationHandlers: path.join(__dirname, './handlers'),
      validateSecurity: {
        handlers: {
          verifyApiKey(req, scopes) {
            return middleware.verifyApiKey(req)
          },
          bearerAuth(req, scopes) {
            return middleware.verifyToken(req)
          }
        }
      },
    }),
  );

  app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(err.status || 500).json({
      message: err.message,
      errors: err.errors,
    });
```

The way I ended up using middleware in my routes is below:

I've added a `securitySchemes` section in my swagger.yml file, like so:

```yaml
components:
  securitySchemes:
    verifyApiKey:
      type: apiKey
      in: header
      name: x-api-key
    bearerAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: JWT
```

There's a bit more information about it here: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/

On each route that needs the middleware, I'm adding a security section, like so:

```yaml
/team:
    post:
      security:
        - bearerAuth: []
      description: Create a new team
      operationId: createTeam
      x-eov-operation-id: createTeam
      x-eov-operation-handler: team
```

As you can see in my code above (in the index.js file), I've got a `validateSecurity` key, with a `handlers` key that then has the  correlating keys that are in my swagger.yml (verifyApiKey and  bearerAuth). These functions get the request and scope to check if they're valid. These functions return a boolean value, so `true` means that the middleware lets the request through, and `false` means a `403` response will be returned.

```
validateSecurity: {
        handlers: {
          verifyApiKey(req, scopes) {
            return middleware.verifyApiKey(req)
          },
          bearerAuth(req, scopes) {
            return middleware.verifyToken(req)
          }
        }
      },
```

Please respond if I've got anything above wrong, or if the explanation can be clearer. If you have questions, please post them below.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass array of handlers instead of just 1 function, like in express.
So in you code, the `getUsers` function that probably is what the x-eov-operation-id refers to, would be an array of 2 functions:

```
const getUsers = [
  apiKeyMiddleware,
  (req, res) => {
    const { 'x-user-id': userId } = req.headers
    res.status(200).json(`Your userId is ${userId}`)
  }
];
```

Answer (score -1):

I was in a similar situation as you, using OpenAPI/Swagger packages like that limited my ability to add specific middleware per endpoint, so my solution was I created an npm module called [@zishone/chaindler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zishone/chaindler).

You can use it like this:

```js
const { Chain } = require('@zishone/chaindler');

function getUsers(req, res) {
  const { 'x-user-id': userId } = req.headers
  res.status(200).json(`Your userId is ${userId}`)
}

function postUsers(req, res) {
  // ...
}

function mw1(req, res, next) {
  next()
}

function mw2(req, res, next) {
  next()
}

module.exports = {
  getUsers: new Chain(mw1, mw2).handle(getUsers),
  postUsers: new Chain(mw1).handle(postUsers)
}
```

Basically it just chains the middlewares then calls them one by one then call the handler/controller last.

Comment: Thanks, I actually found a way to do this without using any packages!